# Selenium driver - wait on page reload

Tags: selenium

Is there a way, how to wait on page reload? For example, when I'm on page `localhost:9000/web` and I instruct the webdriver again to navigate to the `localhost:9000/web`. I don't want or can't indicate the reloading by waiting on some elements.

Answer (score 6):

In Selenium WebDriver we can implement waitForPageToLoad using the following code snippet :

```java
public void waitForPageToLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    ExpectedCondition < Boolean > pageLoad = new
    ExpectedCondition < Boolean > () {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };

    Wait < WebDriver > wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    try {
        wait.until(pageLoad);
    } catch (Throwable pageLoadWaitError) {
        assertFalse("Timeout during page load", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is old but I also wanted a solution for this, and stumbled onto this question.

Thanks to the answers posted, I created my own solution by combining the expected condition of staleness of the html and the `waitForPageToLoad` function from @mfsi_sitamj post.

Something like this:

```
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(tagName = "html")
private WebElement __document;

public void waitForReload() {
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(this.__document));
    wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
        ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
}
```

Comment: This approach is the best for me. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/32278904/349169

Comment: I have also created a function that will insert a random unique javascript variable `ex: selenium_97651623763774623` into the page after page load and a function that checks that variable, if it does not exist anymore, the page has been unloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium RC, then it's the `waitForPageToLoad()` method.

```
selenium.waitForPagetoLoad() // it might be waitForLoad() - can't remember.
```

If you are using Selenium WebDriver, then all navigations are handled by the API and it will wait implicitly until the browser is done navigating.

```
driver.navigate().to().url("http://localhost:9000/web");
```

Also, make sure you are putting the "http://" at the beginning. Selenium might not be resolving "localhost:9000"

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver methods like get(), navigate.to(), navigate.refresh(), navigate.forward(), navigate.backward() waits automatically till the next page gets loaded completely.

In Selenium RC, we can acheive that using

```
new Selenium().waitForPagetoLoad()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can set pageLoadTimeout, once set it wil be there throught the webdriver session, and if the exception is thrown because of timeout then we can't restore same session so need to create new instance.

```
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //waits 10 seconds for page to load
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        try {
            driver.get("https://yourdomain.com");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();

            //create new instance of webdriver
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            //waits 5 minutes for page to load
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://yourdomain.com");
        }
```