# Selenium webdriver 2.47.1 how to wait for a page reload

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm using webdriver(java) for a unique test where a page reloads itself when you log on, I've been unable to wait for the element to load because it is already there before the reload.  So far the only way I've been able to get it to work is to use a thread.sleep, is there a way to listen for a page refresh?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to solve this is, to get a reference to the element you need, that appears both on the login-page and the reloaded page.
Then you can use the `ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf` to occur, and then you can be sure, that the element is removed from the DOM and a new element is created. Well, the last part is not guaranteed by this method, but at least you know that the old element is gone.

The code could look something like this:

```
WebElement elementOldPage = driver.findElement(By.id("yourid"));

... do login etc ...

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(elementOldPage));

WebElement elementNewPage = driver.findElement(By.id("yourid"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I ll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32278904/13641055) from Kim Schiller one might be interested in the following piece of code. It is surely not perfect due to the sleeps, so be free to suggest improvements to make it more bulletproof. Also note I'm no expert with selenium.

The if branch waits for the top level node in the html to go stale in case of a page reload. The else branch simply waits until the drivers url matches the request url in case we load a different page.

```py
def safe_page_load(url):
    if driver.current_url == url:
        tmp = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html')
        driver.get(url)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(ExpectedConditions.staleness_of(tmp))
    else:
        driver.get(url)
        while(driver.current_url) != url:
            sleep(0.3)
    sleep(0.3)
```

Happy if I could help someone.